# IIB Mapping. Collect values from array to one String

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

I have JSON array of objects as input. Each object has field 'description'. I want to collect all 'description' values as single String for output

[image]

Help me please to figure out the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=SSTTDS_11.0.0/com.ibm.gdm.doc/cm28640_.htm

I think you need fn:string-join()